# Investigating the Claim: co-$NP\subseteq NP\text{/}P$ implies $\Sigma_3^P=\Pi_3^P$ and Collapse of the Polynomial Hierarchy?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, circuits

I have been studying the polynomial hierarchy recently, and I came across an intriguing claim that I would like to explore further:

Assuming co-$NP\subseteq NP\text{/}P$, the claim states that it implies $\Sigma_3^P=\Pi_3^P$, which, in turn, leads to the conclusion that $PH=\Pi_3^P=\Sigma_3^P$.

I find this claim fascinating, but I am currently unable to provide a proof for it. If anyone has any insights on how to prove this result or knows of any relevant research papers that could help me understand and demonstrate this claim, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know the Karp–Lipton theorem?

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as “NP/P”. It’s **NP/poly**, meaning NP with polynomial advice, or equivalently, languages definable by polynomial-size nondeterministic circuits.

Comment: Yea I know it's NP/poly but I saw it written in some places as NP/P. I heard of Karp-Lipton theorem but I don't know its details. Would it help me prove the claim? And is there any source you can provide that would help me study it?

Comment: Writing NP/P makes no sense, as polynomial advice has nothing to do whatsoever with the class of polynomial-time languages. You can find a proof of Karp–Lipton in basic textbooks such as Arora&Barak, or in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%E2%80%93Lipton_theorem). The statement in the question is a variant of the Karp–Lipton theorem, and can be proved in an analogous way. (After a bit of manipulation, you can think of it as the Karp–Lipton theorem relativized with an NP-complete oracle.)